# ROS move_base D* (DStar) Pathplanning Algorithm implementation

Tags: algorithm, ros, path-finding

I am trying to find an implementation of the D* (lite) algorithm for the ROS move_base package.

So far I could only find 2:

- https://github.com/Botao-Hu/Dstar-lite-on-ROS-Turtlebot - 
  Even if the pdf states that they used it the code for the planning just creates a straight line.
- https://github.com/Intermodalics/srl_dstar_lite - Does not work, console output: NO PATH FOUND FROM THE D* Lite PLANNER

Can you suggest me any code?

I am using ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04 with Gazebo9 and Turtlebot3

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I have an implementation of the D* Lite optimized version in python. It works, however I have a minor detail difference from the original pseudo code explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61467693/d-lite-search-algorithm-for-robot-path-planning-gets-stuck-in-infinite-loop-wh). If you care to take a look on this question on stack overflow, I'd be happy. I have yet to implement in ROS. But that should be a rather straight forward thing to do as the OccupancyGrid class I made is compatible with the nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid message type in ROS. I have implemented both A* and RRT* earlier with the same configuration, so I know it should work.